# Why does calling filter on a vector not remove elements from the vector?

Tags: rust, higher-order-functions

I am writing a small program that finds a winner of a marathon. 
Everything seems logical until I try to filter the vector for runners that are late for some amount of time. The vector remains same after the filter function, and if use `iter_mut()` it states type errors.

```
fn main() {
    let mut input_line = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_line);
    let n = input_line.trim().parse::<u8>().unwrap();
    let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(n as usize);
    for _ in 0..n {
        let mut input_line = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_line);
        let separated = input_line.trim().split(":").collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let hours = separated[0].parse::<u8>().unwrap();
        let minutes = separated[1].parse::<u8>().unwrap();
        let seconds = separated[2].parse::<u8>().unwrap();
        v.push((hours, minutes, seconds));
    }

    //println!("{:?}", v);
    filter_hours(&mut v);
    filter_minutes(&mut v);
    filter_seconds(&mut v);
    println!("{:?}", v[0]);

    println!("{:?}", v);
}

fn filter_hours(v: &mut Vec<(u8, u8, u8)>) {
    let (mut minimum, _, _) = v[0];
    for &i in v.iter() {
        let (h, _, _) = i;
        if h < minimum {
            minimum = h;
        }
    }
    v.iter().filter(|&&(h, _, _)| h == minimum);
}

fn filter_minutes(v: &mut Vec<(u8, u8, u8)>) {
    let (_, mut minimum, _) = v[0];
    for &i in v.iter() {
        let (_, m, _) = i;
        if m < minimum {
            minimum = m;
        }
    }
    v.iter().filter(|&&(_, m, _)| m == minimum);
}

fn filter_seconds(v: &mut Vec<(u8, u8, u8)>) {
    let (_, _, mut minimum) = v[0];
    for &i in v.iter() {
        let (_, _, s) = i;
        if s < minimum {
            minimum = s;
        }
    }
    v.iter().filter(|&&(_, _, s)| s == minimum);
}
```

Comment: You haven't specified what the actual question is.  You mention you find something confusing, but don't tell us what it is.

Comment: I apologize for ambiguity. My questions are regarding the three "filter..." functions, and I stated the whole main function, so you could see on what I am using those functions. My questions are why do I have to use the double references, and why does the vector remains same after the three filters. Input could be: 
3 \n
10:23:01 \n
3:09:18 \n
22:11:54

Comment: I am trying to use the filter function and destructuring.

Comment: The vector remains same after the filter function, and if use iter_mut() it states type errors.

Comment: You should edit your clarification into the question so people don't have to read the comments to know what you're asking

Comment: Still nothing happened. The vector remains same after the filters.

Comment: @NemanjaBeric As already said, please EDIT your question to add the information, do not use comments for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterators do not alter the number of items in the original data structure. Instead, you want to use [`retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain):

```
fn filter_hours(v: &mut Vec<(u8, u8, u8)>) {
    let min = v.iter().map(|&(h, _, _)| h).min().unwrap();
    v.retain(|&(h, _, _)| h == min);
}
```

Comment: This is even simpler: `let min = v.iter().min_by_key(|x| x.0).unwrap();`

Comment: @Boiethios maybe... although that returns the `&(u8, u8, u8)` so you have to pull the value out and make sure the reference doesn't live too long and collide with the call to `retain`. Something like `v.iter().min_by_key(|x| x.0).unwrap().0`.

Comment: The reference is ok, because `v` lives during the whole function. For the retain, you can do `v.retain(|x| x.0 == min.0);`

Comment: @Boiethios nope, that's what I mean about too long: ``cannot borrow `*v` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable``

Answer (score 4):

Note that `filter` operates on an iterator, not on the vector; it removes elements from the iterator and not from the vector. One way to do what you want is to collect the result of `filter` into a new vector and replace the old one with it: `v = v.iter().filter(whatever).collect();` but this will allocate space for a new vector, copy the elements from the old vector into the new one, then free the old vector.

There is an experimental API, [`drain_filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain_filter), which allows you to modify the vector and remove matching elements in place. However since it is experimental, this API is only available in nightly for the time being.

If you want to keep to stable Rust and avoid the overhead of `collect`, you will need to remove the elements by hand. Something like this should do it (taken from the `drain_filter` docs):

```
let mut i = 0;
while i != vec.len() {
    if some_predicate(&mut vec[i]) {
        let val = vec.remove(i);
        // your code here
    } else {
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is written in the warning: **warning: unused `std::iter::Filter` which must be used: iterator adaptors are lazy and do nothing unless consumed**. I wonder why people do not read the warnings.

Comment: The code can be simplified to `vec.retain(|e| !some_predicate(e))`